# Running in "No report files specified" when trying to generate test coverage in docker pipeline (Linux)

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, nunit, test-coverage

I use a **linux-based docker pipeline** to build and do automatic testing with the **NUnit** Framework in a **C#-.NET-Core** based solution.

"Test" job in my .gitlab-ci.yml-File:

```
runTests:
  stage: test
  image: docker-registry.xyz.de/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}/build:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}_backend_${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
  services:
    - name: atsnngs/mysql-aurora-compatible
      alias: mysql_test

  tags:
    - docker
    - linux
    - shared
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 30m
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/pages
  script:
    - mkdir $CI_PROJECT_DIR/pages
    - mkdir mkdir /tmp/pages
    - cd /app
    - nohup dotnet run --project ./ServiceLoader/ServiceLoader.csproj Test > dotnetcore.log &
    - sleep 10s && dotnet test -v normal /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover /p:Exclude=[NUnit3.TestAdapter]*
    - reportgenerator -reports:/app/Tests/coverage.opencover.xml -targetdir:/tmp/pages
    - ls -l /tmp/pages
    - mv /tmp/pages/index.htm /tmp/pages/index.html
    - mv /tmp/pages $CI_PROJECT_DIR/
  dependencies:
    - build
```

In the Dockerfile, which I use to build the image I am using to execute testing, I install the report generation tool (For readability reasons I skipped the dotnet restore and build parts of the Dockerfile):

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build

# install reportgenerator
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool
ENV PATH /root/.dotnet/tools:$PATH
```

But when I ran the pipeline the report generation fails:

```
$ reportgenerator -reports:/app/Tests/coverage.opencover.xml -targetdir:/tmp/pages
No report files specified.
```

I have already compared the Dockerfile and .gitlab-ci.yml file with another project I used this approach and could not find any difference which could explain this error. Is there any other place where I need to have a look at?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is solved through adding the **Nuget packages** for **coverlet.msbuild** and **dotnet-reportgenerator-cli**. These packages are missing and lead to the error in the report generation.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    ...
    <PackageReference Include="Nunit" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.msbuild" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="dotnet-reportgenerator-cli" Version="4.0.5-rc2" />

  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had multiple  defined in the csproj file. Removing „net48“ and other legacy .NET framework TFMs helped in my case.